# JavaScript: Successively calling a list of functions on an object

Tags: javascript, function, method-chaining, function-composition

Let's say I have a list of functions stored in an array:

```
var myFunctions = [
    function (i) {return i + 2},
    function (i) {return i * 2},
    function (i) {return i - 3}
]
```

What would be the best way to successively call all these functions an object, i.e. to get `((n + 2) * 2) - 3` as a result?

Answers using external libraries like [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) are welcome :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrays are also JavaScript objects. In your case, you created an array and three properties to it, namely `f1`, `f2` and `f3`. Instead, you can simply do

```
var myFunctions = [
    function(i) {
        return i + 2
    },
    function(i) {
        return i * 2
    },
    function(i) {
        return i - 3
    }
];
```

Now that we have an array of functions, we can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to apply these functions like this

```
var result = myFunctions.reduce(function(result, currentFunction) {
    return currentFunction(result);
}, n);
```

The `n` is the actual initial value to be passed to the list of functions to be applied. `reduce` takes the initial value and the first function and passes them as the `result` and `currentFunction` respectively. We apply the `currentFunction` on `result` and return the value. In the next iteration, the returned value will be the `result` and the `currentFunction` will be the second function and so on.

If you don't like the functional approach, you can simply use a for loop, like this

```
var i = 0, result = 0, n = 10;
for (var i = 0; i < myFunctions.length; i += 1) {
    n = myFunctions[i](n);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using fold (reduce):

```
var n = 5;

var myFunctions = [
    function (i) {return i + 2},
    function (i) {return i * 2},
    function (i) {return i - 3}
];

n = myFunctions.reduce(function(n, fn) { return fn(n) }, n);

n; // => 11 ((5 + 2) * 2 - 3)
```

Using [function composition](http://underscorejs.org/#compose):

```
var myFunctions = [
    function (i) {return i - 3},
    function (i) {return i * 2},
    function (i) {return i + 2}
];

_.compose.apply(null, myFunctions)(5); // => 11
```

Note that in this second example the functions are in reverse order, by convention the last function in the chain is applied first.

Answer (score 0):

Passing @Sacha’s original demand and @thefourtheye’s answer through a small anonymous function lifting, this can be expressed as follow:

```js
const inception = 42; // or anything you prefer really.
const modifiers = [
  i => i - 3,
  i => i * 2,
  i => i + 2
];

// Apply successively each generated function on its predecessor result,
// taking inception as initial origin.
modifiers.reduce((origin, transform) => transform(origin), inception)
```

Note also how this snippet only use constants, which better reflect the fact that source parameters are never altered.